# How to check if game was started once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game I have main menu with the "New game" button. I need to check, if I press this button first time in this game session like:

I start new game with this button (press first time), then from the game I come back to the main menu, then I press this button again (press not first time).

```
public void ButtonNewGame()
 {
     if() // if the game was started once
     {
         GameObject gameMAnagerObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameManager");
         GameManager gameManagerScript = gameMAnagerObj.GetComponent<GameManager>();
         gameManagerScript.currentActNumber = 0;
         act_0.stepNumber = 0;
     }
     SceneManager.LoadScene("Casino");
 }
```

Comment: Not a duplicate, that answer would work only for the very first time the game was EVER run (persisted player prefs), and not the first time the scene was loaded inside the executable. This user needs the behaviours loaded, and thus need it every time the executable was started.

Comment: @ParadoxForge Check if "How to check if game was started once". Very very similar and will solve OP's problem. `PlayerPrefs` is the way to go. It works even when the game is closed and re-opened. Please explain why it is not a duplicate

Comment: I saw the title, and the user gave it the wrong title, but look at what he's doing. The playerpref's solution will not solve what this user is trying to do.

Comment: @Programmer Not a duplicate.  I agree with **Paradox**.  OP's problem is simply a game state issue concerning `in menu` or `in game` **not** preventing _multiple instances of a Windows process_

Comment: @dima Look into _state machines_

Comment: @MickyD Ok. I assumed that OP wanted this to stay between scenes since there is `SceneManager.LoadScene("Casino");` in the code. If that is true then, `PlayerPrefs` should do it, else he should go with `static`. I don't see why OP should worry about state machines since this is just a simple `true` or `false` check. Just keep it simple. Happy coding!

Comment: @Programmer No worries, you too buddy :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static bool IsStartedFirstTime = false;

public void ButtonNewGame()
{
    if(IsStartedFirstTime == false) // if the game was started once
    {
        IsStartedFirstTime = true;
        //Logic on first time run 
        //return;  //depending on your intent, you might wish to return or not!
    }
    if(IsStartedFirstTime)
        // your logic that happens if it is already started      
}
```

Comment: in this case `your logic here` will execute every time

Comment: that is what the OP wants

Comment: Don't use static.

Comment: You will have to explain a bit more than that, "Dont use statics" is a fundamentally invalid argument. Statics have a specific purpose, and should be used after considering the side effects.

Comment: In the question, he asked a session level solution, statics are application level variables, so here, static variable doesn't have a time or place :)

Comment: static, no harms.

Comment: @Umer Sufyan I'm not sure what you're talking about, a static is fine for this purpose

Comment: @David Suppose two players are playing at same time. Player 1 start game first,Logic that runs on first time load runs and IsStartedFirstTime becomes true. As this variable is static,so when Player 2 start his game, He will find that variable value is true so Logic that runs on first time load wont run. I think that's why static shouldn't be used.

Comment: I mean at the time of second `if` check the `IsStartedFirstTime` is always true. If you claim this is by design, why the `if` at all? It only hurts readability

Comment: @UmerSufyan, no that is not the scenarios the OP wish to convey. It is in a button click event handler, not in the start() or awake() functions. In such cases, no matter the button click event is triggered via player 1, 2, or 3, it is ALL considered as "First time start".

Comment: @slawekwin, see updated answer. I added return clause, but commented, which depends on the logic you want to implement. Hope this clarifies. Thanks for point out this possible scenario.

Comment: @UmerSufyan _"...statics are application level variables..."_ - actually they are `AppDomain`-level and an application can have multiple `AppDomain`s.    But I am probably being too finicky :)